# Merge two DataFrames based on columns and values of a specific column with Pandas in Python 3.x

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

Hello i have a problem which i am not able to implement a solution on.
I have following two DataFrames:

```
>>> df1
A  B   date
1  1  01-2016
2  1  02-2017
1  2  03-2017
2  2  04-2020

>>> df2
A  B  01-2016  02-2017  03-2017  04.2020
1  1    0.10    0.22     0.55     0.77
2  1    0.20    0.12     0.99     0.125
1  2    0.13    0.15     0.15     0.245
2  2    0.33    0.1      0.888    0.64
```

What i want is following DataFrame:

```
>>> df3
A  B   date      value
1  1  01-2016    0.10
2  1  02-2017    0.12
1  2  03-2017    0.15
2  2  04-2020    0.64
```

I already tried following:

```
        summarize_dates = self.summarize_specific_column(data=df1, column='date')

        for date in summarize_dates:
            left_on = np.append(left_on, date)
            right_on = np.append(right_on, merge_columns.upper())
            result = pd.merge(left=df2, right=df1,
                              left_on=left_on, right_on=right_on,
                              how='right')
            print(result)
```

This does not work. Can you help me and suggest a more comfortable implementation? Manyy thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to melt df2 and then do a left join on df1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what do you mean with melt the Frame? Edit: Was already answered. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lookup`

```
df1['value']=df2.set_index(['A','B']).lookup(df1.set_index(['A','B']).index,df1.date)
df1
Out[228]: 
   A  B     date  value
0  1  1  01-2016   0.10
1  2  1  02-2017   0.12
2  1  2  03-2017   0.15
3  2  2  04-2020   0.64
```

Comment: Works fine! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

You can melt df2 and then merge using the default 'inner' merge

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2.melt(id_vars = ['A', 'B'], var_name='date'))

    A   B   date    value
0   1   1   01-2016 0.10
1   2   1   02-2017 0.12
2   1   2   03-2017 0.15
3   2   2   04-2020 0.64
```

Comment: Thank you i will try that out!

Comment: Works fine! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MichaelGann, don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer that you find to be the most suitable.